# How to pass Array value inside Array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to Arrays and I want to pass and get value from my first array.

The code look like this:

My first array is:

```
const CompanyData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Company1', phone: 'X', address: 'Y' , person: [1, 2]},
    {id: 2, name: 'Company2', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Company3', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'}
  ];
```

My second array is:

```
const PersonData = [
{id: 1, name: 'A', phone: 'D', address: 'X'},
{id: 2, name: 'B', phone: 'D', address: 'X'},
{id: 3, name: 'C', phone: 'D', address: 'X'}
];
```

How can I pass and get value from **PersonData** inside **CompanyData** on **person** array?

If this is possible, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output? Also please care to add what have you tried to achieve it

Comment: are you trying to create a new array such that the id's of each array are joined?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### How about Map instead?

The way I see it, arrays aren't a good data structure option for what you're trying to achieve. Since it has no keys, you'd have to iterate through all of the arrays until you're finding what you're looking for. Which is fine for this amount of data but can get really slow when things start to scale.

You could use Map instead. Which uses a key to identify value.

```
// Crete a Map Object
const PersonMap = new Map();

// Convert your Array to Map Format
PersonData.forEach(function(person) {
  PersonMap.set(person.id, person);
});

// Get a person by Id
console.log(PersonMap.get(1)); // Outputs {id: 1, name: 'A', phone: 'D', address: 'X'}
```

So with that, in CompanyData[0].person (or any other, of course) you can then push PersonMap.get(1) and PersonMap.get(2).

```
// Make it an empty array
CompanyData[0].person = [];

// Push a single entry for each person
CompanyData[0].person.push(PersonMap.get(1));
CompanyData[0].person.push(PersonMap.get(2));

// This will give the intended result
```

Or you could batch push it all.

```
// Push all, automatically
CompanyData.forEach(function(company) {
  if(company.person) { // Since some companies doesn't have any person
    company.person = company.person.map(function(person) {
      return PersonMap.get(person);
    });
  }
});
```

---

#### What if I wanted to use Maps since the beginning?

You'll have to declare the key. Map.size is like the length property of the array, returning the amount os entries inside. So you could build the Map like this:

```
const PersonData = new Map();

PersonData.set(PersonData.size + 1, {
  id: PersonData.size + 1,
  name: 'A',
  phone: 'D',
  address: 'X'
});
```

More of Maps, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

---

#### Nope? Only arrays? Ok

Whatever, if you want to still use an array, I'll have to check if the id is equal though every iteration, until you find what you're looking for, resulting in something like this:

```
// For + If Solution
CompanyData.forEach(function(company) { // For every company
  if(company.person) { // If company has persons
    company.person = company.person.map(function(member) { // For every person in company (member)
      for(let person of PersonData) { // Looks for every person
        if(member === person.id) return person; // If is the person
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```
// Filter Solution
CompanyData.forEach(function(company) { // For every company
  if(company.person) { // If company has persons
    company.person = company.person.map(function(member) { // For every person in company (member)
      return PersonData.filter(function(person) { return person.id === member });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

as per mentioned description.

```js
const CompanyData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Company1', phone: 'X', address: 'Y' ,person: [1,2]},
    {id: 2, name: 'Company2', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Company3', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'}
  ]
  
  const PersonData = [
{id: 1, name: 'A', phone: 'D', address: 'X'},
{id: 2, name: 'B', phone: 'D', address: 'X'},
{id: 3, name: 'C', phone: 'D', address: 'X'}
]

CompanyData[0].person = [...PersonData];
console.log(CompanyData);
```

Comment: Note that this will be a shallow copy. Namely if you modify the object inside the person field you will modify the PersonData too

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get a Person data as per the id then the better will be to create a function and from there return the element of the PersonData

```
const PersonData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'A', phone: 'D', address: 'X'},
    {id: 2, name: 'B', phone: 'D', address: 'X'},
    {id: 3, name: 'C', phone: 'D', address: 'X'}
]


const getPerson=(...args)=>{
    console.log(args)
    const Person=[];
    args.forEach(x=>{
        Person.push(PersonData.filter(y=>y.id===x))
    })
    return Person;
}
const CompanyData = [
{id: 1, name: 'Company1', phone: 'X', address: 'Y' , person: getPerson(1,2)},
{id: 2, name: 'Company2', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'},
{id: 3, name: 'Company3', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'}
]
```

You will get array inside CompanyData[0].person

You can edit the getPerson function as you want and it is just the idea of how you can make it compatible with multiple values and return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const CompanyData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Company1', phone: 'X', address: 'Y' , person: [1,2]},
    {id: 2, name: 'Company2', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Company3', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'}
  ]
const PersonData = [
{id: 1, name: 'A', phone: 'D', address: 'X'},
{id: 2, name: 'B', phone: 'D', address: 'X'},
{id: 3, name: 'C', phone: 'D', address: 'X'}
];

CompanyData.forEach(comp => {
  if (comp.person) {
    comp.person = comp.person.map(personId => PersonData.find(person => person.id === personId));
  }
});

console.log(CompanyData);
```

Comment: Don't use comment for such please, by the way I dont copy ?

Comment: @RadicalEdward I don't say that you have copied. I just suggest not to duplicate answer. Before posting answer please see that same answer is already available or not.

Comment: Its 3 min of difference, din't recognize yours when I started. sorry if you don't mean that.

Comment: @RadicalEdward Many time I have deleted my answer just for seconds differences.

Comment: Really appretiated. your code is better than mine. but sometimes just solution doesn't matter but explaination too. not this case though.

Comment: Will delete for the first time on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote two script for that. in the first one I only show how to add person data in "companyData" array first object. but in the second one with a "for-in-loop" I added the data for each person to the each object of "companyData" array. I also changed the name of properties in "personData" array for clear understanding.

```js
//script1 
let personData = [
    {idPer: 1, namePer: 'Company1', phonePer: 'X', addressPer: 'Y'},
    {idPer: 2, namePer: 'Company2', phonePer: 'X', addressPer: 'Y'},
    {idPer: 3, namePer: 'Company3', phonePer: 'X', addressPer: 'Y'}
  ];

let person = personData[1].namePer;

let companyData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Company1', phone: 'X', address: 'Y' , personDataInp: person},
    {id: 2, name: 'Company2', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Company3', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'}
  ];
  
  console.log(companyData);
  
  //script2
  
let personData2 = [
    {idPer: 1, namePer: 'Company1', phonePer: 'X', addressPer: 'Y'},
    {idPer: 2, namePer: 'Company2', phonePer: 'X', addressPer: 'Y'},
    {idPer: 3, namePer: 'Company3', phonePer: 'X', addressPer: 'Y'}
  ];


let companyData2 = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Company1', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Company2', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Company3', phone: 'X', address: 'Y'}
  ];

for(i in companyData2) {
    companyData2[i].personDataInp = personData2[i].namePer;
}

console.log(companyData2);
```